# Screen recording in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a screen recording feature in xamarin.forms app.

I only found taking a screenshot
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot).
Is it possible to implement this feature?

Comment: Check [Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording](https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording/tree/main/src/Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording) by Gerald Versluis, this one is for maui, but the source code is there, you can make the same for your xamarin forms app on each platforms and implement it with [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/).

For Android, you can use the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#audio-record-permission) to capture the screen.

For IOS, you can use the [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession?language=objc).